# How to remove extra characters from all cells that are unicode

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im trying to use a spreadsheet someone sent me as a source for importing into a database and in the process I discovered that the cell values have extra characters in them. The unicode character is U+00C2
How can I remove those characters?

Answer (score 0):

Is that `Â`?  You can use Find/Replace:

`Range("A1:A10").Replace ChrW(&HC2), ""`

in VBA, or just do a regular FIND/REPLACE, and insert the character into the "FIND" and keep "REPLACE" empty.